# extract to a variable out of a bash script

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script (minimised): called "myScript"

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for var in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
do
sed -e "s/\\begin{document}/\\begin{document}\\\include{fileName_${var}}/g" fileName_MAIN.tex>xfileName_MAIN_$var.tex
done
```

I call this by typing `myScript` into a terminal. It works (well, the full script does). What I would like is to use the script for different filenames. At present the script has the filename hard coded in it as fileName. How can I extract the use of "fileName" (occuring three times once with an x appended at the front) to a variable so that I type into a terminal `myScript newFileName`?

I think I am correct to say that I would like to "lambda extract".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Direct answer to question

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in "$@"
do
    for var in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
    do
        sed -e "s/\\begin{document}/\\begin{document}\\\include{${file}_${var}}/g" \
            ${file}_MAIN.tex > x${file}_MAIN_${var}.tex
    done
done
```

The code iterates over all the file name arguments (`"$@"`), and for each one runs the command with `${file}` appearing where your `fileName` appeared originally.

This means you can use:

```sh
myScript newFileName oldFileName spareFile otherFile
```

and process all 4 files.  Note that things will go haywire if you ever try:

```
myScript /why/did/this/fail/filename
```

If it is important that works, there are ways around it.

#### Handling options

> How would one adapt this to have two arguments, say, if I want the for loop to only go up to 05?

You'd have to decide how you want the command invoked.  There are two main options, it seems to me:

```
myScript 5 file1 [file2 ...]
myScript [-n 5] file1 [file2 ...]
```

In the first, you always have to specify the upper end of the range.  In the second, you can omit a number (which would then default to 10, presumably).  I think it is the better way to go — the existing scripts that expect to map numbers up to 10 will work fine.  So, you need to use `getopts`.

```
#!/bin/bash

number=10
while getopts n: arg
do
    case "$arg" in
    (n) number=$OPTARG;;
    (*) echo "Usage: $0 [-n number] file [...]" >&2; exit 1;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

for file in "$@"
do
    for var in $(seq -f '%02.0f' 1 $number)
    do
        sed -e "s/\\begin{document}/\\begin{document}\\\include{${file}_${var}}/g" \
            ${file}_MAIN.tex > x${file}_MAIN_${var}.tex
    done
done
```

I'm blithely assuming you won't need leading zeros on numbers larger than 99, and that you will provide a number after `-n`.  If you don't, GIGO — Garbarge In, Garbage Out.  If other people are going to use this, you need to be more protective and validate that the number is in fact a number, etc.  However, a bigger problem for the general user would be checking the constraints on the file names, ensuring that all the files that are supposed to exist do in fact exist.  Consequently, I don't regard the issue as serious; this is a personal-use script.

Comment: Many thanks. Out of interest, how would one adapt this to have two arguments, say, if I want the for loop to only go up to 05?

Comment: Your answer contains much that needs to be learnt! Many thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you have access to [positional parameters](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams) ($0, $1..$n).

`$0` is the name of the script you call and `$1` is the first parameter passed. `$2` is the second parameter, and it goes on. When you reach to tenth parameter, you'll have to wrap the number in bracket, like so: `${10}`.

Although this will only work for 1 file, modifying your script like so would allow you to call it like: `myScript file`.

```
for var in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
do
  sed -e "s/\\begin{document}/\\begin{document}\\\include{$1_${var}}/g" \
    $1_MAIN.tex > x$1_MAIN_${var}.tex
done
```

Comment: What you say is accurate, but I'm not sure how it is relevant.  How are you going to use `$1` in the script in the question?  (It can be done with `$1`; I'm not sure you'd ever use `$2` in the script, though.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've added an example of how the positional parameters would be used. Maybe I'm wrong or this is not an advanced answer but this seems to be working. Agreed that `$2` would not be used in this situation, I was just trying to provided a bit more information related to positional parameters (although it could be used to control how many iterations to go through). Care to enlighten me as to why this is irrelevant to the question ?